# Google Analytics with too low of bounce rate

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking for some assistance here. We're seeing a very low bounce rate (3%) which i know can't be possible.

The analytics appears to be setup incorrectly on our site.  We see a lot of event tracking that happens automatically so i'm pretty sure this is our problem.  Here is the code we're seeing that was implemented in what looks to be twice.  Which do we need to get rid of?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxx- 
1`enter code here`"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1');
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

gr8rck

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you've provided looks fine. If the same set of code has been provided twice, remove one of the instances.

You mentioned that a series of events fire automatically. This is most likely what is causing an artificially low bounce rate.

If these events fire without user involvement, my suggestion is that you define them as non-interaction events. The events will still record, but will not count as a true user interaction. Therefore your bounce rate will be unaffected.

You would send a non-interaction event like so:

```
gtag('event', 'my_event_action', {
  'event_label': 'my_event_label',
  'event_category': 'my_event_category',
  'non_interaction': true
});
```